# SQLAlchemy - set value in model using database column name, not property name

Tags: python, database, model, sqlalchemy, mapping

I have a table with the column `TS_TEST_ID`.  I have a SQLAlchemy model with the following property:

```
id = Column(u'TS_TEST_ID', INTEGER(), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
```

Is there any way to set `id` on an instance of my model class when only `TS_TEST_ID` is known?  That is, I only know the name of the column in the database, and I want to somehow map that to `id` and set the `id` property on my model.  I was hoping just doing `MyModel(**{'TS_TEST_ID':1})` would work, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 111,
   in initialize_instance
    return manager.events.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative.py", line 1377,
   in _declarative_constructor
    (k, cls_.__name__))
TypeError: 'TS_TEST_ID' is an invalid keyword argument for MyModel
```

I would rather not have to define `TS_TEST_ID = Column(u'TS_TEST_ID', INTEGER(), primary_key=True, nullable=False)` for every column in my model, either, or even a method called `TS_TEST_ID` that returns the `id` property.

Comment: Can't check it anywere, so just a wild guess: does `yourobj.c.TS_TEST_ID = 15` do the trick?

Comment: An instance of `MyModel` doesn't have a `c` property, but I can access the same thing (I think) through `myobj.__mapper__.c`, and trying to access `myobj.__mapper__.c.TS_TEST_ID` fails with an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems more complicated than it needs to be, but it works.  I'm hoping there's a more direct way of doing this...

```
@staticmethod
def fromFieldHash(h):
    row = MyModel()
    cols = list(row.__table__._columns)
    for k, v in h.iteritems():
        col = find(lambda c: c.key == k, cols)
        # See http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/06Migration#AnImportantExpressionLanguageGotcha
        if col is not None:
            prop = row.__mapper__._columntoproperty[col].key
            setattr(row, prop, v)
    return row
```

The `find` method I'm using is from [Cleanest Python find-in-list function](http://tomayko.com/writings/cleanest-python-find-in-list-function).

Comment: It seems `Mapper.columntoproperty` has been protected (prefixed with `_`), so this'll require some tweaking. Prolly a call to [`Mapper.get_property_by_column()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.get_property_by_column) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If one would like `__init__` to handle both attributes and columns, though having a dedicated `classmethod` factory seems like a cleaner approach, the following implementation could be used as an abstract base:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


def _create_col_lookup(mapper):
    return {c.name: k for k, c in mapper.columns.items()}


class ColBase(Base):

    __abstract__ = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create a lookup of column name -> attr key
        ctoa = _create_col_lookup(inspect(self).mapper)

        # Process intersecting keys
        for k in ctoa.keys() & kwargs.keys():
            setattr(self, ctoa[k], kwargs.pop(k))

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using the above the following asserts pass:

```
class Foo(ColBase):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar = Column('Baz 1')

f = Foo(**{'Baz 1': 1})
assert f.bar == 1

f = Foo(**{'bar': 1})
assert f.bar == 1
```